# Is there a difference in the compiler between struct and class with public members and no constructor

Tags: c++

I'm looking at some legacy code that looks like it was converted over from C to C++ and there are various classes that have public member variables and nothing else:

```
class sampleClass
  public:
    int fd;
    customType clientHandle;
    customType serverHandle;
};
```

From my understanding struct = class with no functions and public members so is this virtually exactly the same as a struct for practical reasons?

What happens when the code is compiled.  Is it compiled down to the exact same "stuff" or do they get compiled differently

Comment: Lack of research on the site strikes back. The most upvoted dupe [was to be found](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5Dstruct+class+difference) in about 20 seconds.

Comment: I specifically asked about the compiler point of view.  The other question relate to design point of view.  Its is a different question.  I want to know how the class and struct is decomposed during compilation.

Comment: Ask the compiler's authors then ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely the same, yes. The only two ways in which structs and classes differ are the default protection of members, and the default inheritance type of base classes.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ only the default accessing differs between struct (public) and class (private).

Answer (score 0):

Difference in struct and class and that is by default members of `struct` are `public`, while by default members of `class` are `private`.

Even while inheriting from `struct`, default specifier is `public`, while for `class` its `private`.

You can see my [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iGeq5eSHsc&list=PLkes6AxGmNZ7AuvPXe9WfwKNIzNPVEg-D&index=7) on this.

Comment: structs also inherit publicly by default while classes inherit privately

Comment: It is not very important, but that is not the only difference. The default inheritance type is also different.

Comment: I have yet to understand the idea of video tutorials. What advantage weights up for the bandwidth loss. Is it, that it's impossible to write up the same?